# PHP MVC: Multiple databases, multiple data mappers?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, datamapper

I am working on my HMVC project.

Right now I am using data mappers in order to move data between the models (domain objects) and a MySQL database. Each mapper receives a MySQL adapter as dependency. The injected adapter receives a PDO instance (a database connection) as dependency and runs sql queries on the database.

I also use a dependency injection container (Auryn).

I'd like to be able to simultaneously retrieve data from storages of different types (MySQL database, PostgreSQL database, XML feeds, etc).

Let's say, I want to retrieve `User` data from a **`PostgreSQL` database** (by using **`PDO`** data-access abstraction), to change it, and to save it into a **`MySQL` database** (by using **`mysqli`** data-access abstraction) on another server. So, there will be different data-access calls for the both database types.

My question is:

Should I create a different mapper for each storage type, like

```
UserMapperPgsql(PgsqlAdapter $adapter) 
UserMapperMySql(MySqlAdapter $adapter)
```

, or should I create only one mapper with more adapters (one for each data type) as dependencies, like bellow?

```
UserMapper(PgsqlAdapter $adapter1, MySqlAdapter $adapter2, ...)
```

Thank you all for your suggestions!

Comment: @tereško Because I wanted to evidentiate, that there will be different data-access calls to different storages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What an odd project you have there.

Anyway. I would go with two separate mappers for separate storage mediums. Because trying to juggle those adapters inside a mapper might end up quite complicated.

That said, depending on how complicated the persistence logic actually ends up, you might benefit from looking up [repositories](https://www.martinfowler.com/eaaCatalog/repository.html) as approach to streamline the API, that gets exposed to where your "application logic" is actually done.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, it seems odd... but it's not :) I've presented a not so good example in my question, I know. Until now I've used factories. Because I have a DIC now, I want to change all. I've implemented repositories already, but I just presented the case of data mappers for the sake of simplicity. Can you please tell me, if something would be different in your answer, if you know that I use repositories?

Comment: @aendeerei the general advice would not change, but it might be better to go with Symfony's standalone [DIC compnent](https://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection.html) for your project, because it's a configuration-based one (which would help with your different connections and remove the need for that "adapter hack") and has a "share by default" behavior.

Comment: I see. Thanks. I appreciate that you have taken your time! I'll take a look on it.