# PHP MVC: Config class as dependency or with just class constants, accessible from overall?

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns, model-view-controller, configuration

In my MVC project (PHP 7.1) I have a `Config` class and a multitude of config files, each of them looking like this:

```
return [
    'web' => [
        'host' => 'localhost',
        //...
    ],
];
```

At the app entry point I make an instance of the `Config` class and load all config file arrays in it. The created object is then passed as constructor argument in all classes that needs it:

```
class AbstractView {

    private $config;

    public function __construct(Config $config) {
        $this->config = $config;
    }

    private function prepareContext() {
        $this->assign('appHost', $this->getConfig()->get('web/host'));
    }

}
```

Because it's quite a "big effort" to pass the `Config` object quite overall in my app, I thought of implementing a `Config` class with only class constants in it, like:

```
class Config {

    const WEB_PROTOCOL = 'http';
    const WEB_HOST = 'localhost';

}
```

and access them from overall directly with

```
class AbstractView {

    private function prepareContext() {
        $this->assign('appHost', Config::WEB_HOST);
    }

}
```

### My questions are:

1. Is this a really good alternative, having in mind that I want to
   completely avoid static states in my app?
2. Is this alternative a "static" one or absolutely not?
3. What about testability (I don't have any experience with it yet)?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you intend to test this code, this will be quite complicated, because you will have to provide a custom autoloaders for each variation, that you want to test (well .. you could also to with a single autoloader, that has some static methods for hanging it's behavior). This will make the whole unit-testing something of a nightmare.

In your position, I would go in a different direction: attempt to segregate the configurations. It seems that you are passing all of the configuration, even though the instance will use only one or two values from it.

This approach results in hidden dependencies, which produce highly coupled code, where you don't actually know, what is necessary for reach of your instances.

#### Recommendation

Start using DI Container in your code.

It will let you offload a lot of the configuration, because some of the "parameters", that you are extracting from configuration, could be passed as direct dependencies in the constructors.

And use the magical `Config` instance, where DIC is not a clean option. Though, you probably should be using multiple `Config` instances, each representing part of settings, that are used together.

Comment: Wow, that's a really good answer, @tereško. But I'm also a little confused by the phrase senses you were using. May I ask you some questions in order to bring my undertand in line with your text? You say: "**_even thought the instance will use..._**", You mean: the instance of the class which receives `Config` object as dependency is using only one or two values from `Config` object, right? Also: you say "**_This approach results in hidden dependencies..._**". Cont...

Comment: As for the hidden dependencies - I didn't really know how to better explain this. From the outside tour class says, that it needs `Config` instance, but what it really want is to pull out a value from that `Config`. It's not really a classical dependency, but, if you try to reuse this code, you will see the same issues as if you has used a *Registry* anti-pattern.  (And, yes, I assume that your `$this->getConfig()->get('something')` returns `null`, if no value is set.)

Comment: [ I deleted this text because you already answered it :-) ] Otherwise I must tell you: your segregation and dependency injection recommendation using a DIC - which I already have, e.g still Auryn - is the idea, that I really didn't thought about. I find it very natural and best practice.

Comment: Yes, by me is also late. But you know how it is: "_I can't sleep without knowing all about configs_" :-) tereško, do you remember your answer to my question from about 5 days ago? [PHP MVC Multiple databases, multiple data mappers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44166994/php-mvc-multiple-databases-multiple-data-mappers). I followed your principle and I'm very happy about it: now I can juggle with multiple connections, mappers, adapters, repositories, without any problems. I thank you again! :-) Good night

Comment: I sometimes use the `Config::WEB_HOST` approach when the value/config wont be tested or need to be checked etc. I.e. some backed enum with a case for Database time format 'YYYY-MM..' etc. Though you should have separate enum classes, such as `ValueObject/Db/DateTimeFormat.php` etc. This does make testing almost impossible, and always hacky at best. But sometimes it's fine imo